# Google Fusion Tables Protected map layer explained?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am using Google Fusion tables in Google Maps API by a FusionTablesLayer method.
The problem is the table has to be unlisted or public in order to be displayed in Google Maps API. Is there any way to make the table private and still use it?

I have read all google info on OAuth and protected map layer, but didn't really get the idea of using OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to display a private table on a Maps API layer,  however you need to sign up for a Google Maps API for Business account. More info here http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2459324?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

To complement javram's answer: 
You do not need to use OAuth for the protected map layer with Fusion Tables Layer.

You might choose to use OAuth to retrieve data from the Fusion Table securely and then use other parts of the Google Maps API to map your data on the client.

Note that if you need to keep the data private, Fusion Tables may not be the right solution for you; You may wish to talk with the Google Maps for Business team about other solutions better geared for business use. 
http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html

-Rebecca

Comment: Thanks. I had a chat with Google, their business services are way too expensive. To put it in simple manner, I want to use Fusion Tables in my application but don't want anybody else to see that table, so people can only see that via my application. Does it make sense?

Comment: I have the same user case as 'Abstract'.